# My prebuilt Stripe checkout page has no image

Tags: stripe-payments

I previously used the prebuilt Stripe checkout page, but I deleted that code and started over. Now I'm trying to add an image to the prebuilt Stripe checkout page and I can't figure out how. [This is the guide I used](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout).This is what the page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/26nNm.jpg

This is my python code:

```py
@bp.route('/create-checkout-session', methods=['POST'])
def create_checkout_session():
    stripe_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price_data': {
                'currency': 'usd',
                'product_data': {
                    'name': 'One Key',
                },
                'unit_amount': 2000,
            },
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/sucess",
        cancel_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/cancel?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
    )

    return redirect(stripe_session.url, code=303)
```

How do I add an image to the prebuilt Stripe checkout page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a Price on your dashboard(https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/products/create) which lets you easily upload an image and use that in `line_items[0].price`  , instead of `price_data`.
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide

[image]

If you want to do this all through code, then you can pass a link to an image  that you've hosted somewhere yourself in `price_data` https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-product_data-images . Note that your image must be public and accessible(since Stripe's servers will access it and copy it to their CDN).